# I wanted to know how we can capture termination of a pipeline task in ADO in shellscript

Tags: shell, azure-devops-server

I have a requirement to invoke a CURL command when a pipeline in ADO is cancelled.
Can someone please let me know how i can capture cancelled status of an ADO pipeline and use that in a shellscript to invoke a CURL command.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how i can capture cancelled status of an ADO pipeline and use that in
> a shellscript to invoke a CURL command.

You can get the execution result of the build pipeline through the rest api below:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=5.1
```

Test in Postman:

[image]

Then you can write a script to get the pipeline result(e.g.`$result = $response.result`), determine whether the result is `canceled`, if it is, invoke a CURL command.